# Rendering a scene as a texture Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to achieve this: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1786 with Three.js.
I have no idea where to start looking. Just passing the scene as a texture gives a type error.

Comment: If you Google "three.js render to texture" one of the results that comes up is [this one](http://ryan-kahn.com/threejs/threejs/examples/webgl_rtt.html). You can take a look at the source how it's done. From what I gather (but have a look for yourself) you set up a second camera, specify a texture target and use that result to texture the objects.

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick :) Should have looked at the examples...

Comment: Good that that solves it. If you can, post what you have done as an answer and accept it. Then we have a clear question/answer pair here for future visitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here: 
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Three.js might not have the best documentation but the examples almost cover every situation.